# How to convert nested OrderedDict to Object

Tags: python, django

I have dictionary like this

```
data = OrderedDict([('name', 'NewIsland'), ('Residents', [OrderedDict([('name', 'paul'), ('age', '23')])])])
```

and I want to convert it to class object.

Here are my django models.

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Residents(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country', related_name='residents')
```

When I code like this

```
result = Country(**data)
```

I got exception

> 'residents' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

How can I convert it to class object that I can access residents with result.residents[idx]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by manually creating child objects

```
residents_data = data.pop('Residents')    
result = Country(**data)
for rdata in residents_data:
    result.residents.add(Residents(**rdata), bulk=False)
```

Comment: I got exception
<Residents: paul> instance isn't saved. Use bulk=False or save the object first.

Comment: @skriex updated asnwer also read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/relations/

Comment: When I add bulk=False, exception changed to "save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'country'. "

Comment: @skriex do you want to put this objects to db?

Comment: never, I already have db, and I just want compare result with db.

Comment: I want to make object type result temporary.

Comment: @skriex In new django version you can't do that with nested objects. If you want to compare objects. You can just do `getattr` and compare them with assert? I think you are having XY problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378.